# Is it possible to use the browser console in a Tinytest context?

Tags: meteor

```
cd ~/my-package
meteor test-packages ./
open localhost:3000
```

I can't seem to use the JS console: Even though `Meteor` can be logged from a client test file, when I enter it in the console, I get `VM10740:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined`. Same goes for other objects like `Accounts`.

I'd like access to these variables and those defined in my package and tests file in order to debug my tests.

[image]

EDIT: In the client test file, this works:

```
window.Meteor = Meteor
window.Accounts = Accounts
...
```

Is there a better way? Or at least a way that automatically goes through all globals? Trying this caused a refresh loop: `_.extend(window, this)`

Comment: From the server-side, you can access the run-time via `meteor shell` command which provides a Node-like REPL terminal.

Comment: Thanks Blaze. I'm getting this error: `shell: You're not in a Meteor project directory.` I'm inside the directory of my Meteor package, which is not inside a Meteor project. Unless there's some special directory for `meteor test-packages` runs, it looks like `meteor shell` doesn't support this situation.

Comment: I think you can access the `Meteor` object via `Package.meteor.Meteor` on the client-side console while you are testing. Hope it helps.

Comment: In fact it seems that all the packages that are loaded by Meteor is accessible via `Package` object.

Comment: Missing `Accounts`, but rest looks good, thanks!